# SwiftData: Removing item from a model causes the deletion of item

Tags: swift, relationship, swift-data

I'm currently struggling with - I think - relationship issues in SwiftData. I have the following two Models, in which I store recipes and in the second one - recipes for the day.

```swift
@Model
final class DailyMenu {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let day: Int8?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction)
    var menuItems: [RecipeItem]?
}
```

```swift
@Model
final class RecipeItem: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var recipeTitle: String?
    
    // MARK: Relationships
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction, inverse: \DailyMenu.menuItems)
    var dailyMenus: [DailyMenu]?
    
}
```

The following function is designed to remove an element from the `DailyMenu.menuItems` by matching the recipeItem:

```swift
private func removeRecipeFromDay(_ recipeItem: RecipeItem) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        guard let startOfTheWeek = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: .now)),
              let adjustedStartOfTheWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: weekOffset, to: startOfTheWeek) else {
            return
        }
        if let currentWeekMenu = weeklyMenus.first(where: { $0.weekStartDate == adjustedStartOfTheWeek }) {
            
            guard let dailyMenu = dailyMenus.first(where: {$0.weeklyMenu == currentWeekMenu && $0.day == Int8(dayOfWeek)}) else {
                return
            }
            
            dailyMenu.menuItems?.removeAll(where: {$0 == recipeItem})
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the `recipeItem` gets deleted from the Model Context, but the expected behaviour is that it would only remove it from `DailyMenu.menuItems` Array.

I've tried setting the relationship `deleteRule` to `.noAction`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using Version 15.2 (15C500b)